# Как в MQTT зарегестрировать устройство на сервере с базой данных?

Tags: mqtt

Используя MQTT нужно зарегестрировать устройство на сервере:

1. Отправить от устройства логин и пароль на сервер
2. На сервере проверить наличие, сделать запись в БД, вернуть токен

В MQTT есть broker, publisher и subscriber, кто из них работает з БД и есть сервером и каким образом сделать связь между ним и девайсом?

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите сделать? Чтобы устройство могло регистрироваться на сайте? На каком сайте? Что конкретно нужно?

Comment: @insolor обновил